# Speech to Text Method Using Python

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, nlp, speech-recognition, text-to-speech

Good day. I am currently working on Machine Translation (Speech-(Text--Text)-Speech) with our local dialects and I already have the speech and text corpus. However, I am facing a problem in recording the speech as input and transcribing it to a text file because the modules available for speech recognition did not cover our dialects, mostly it just supports English and other major languages.

Is there anyone who know how I can fix it? I would be honored to accept your valuable suggestions and it will help me a lot on my studies. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Are you looking into transcribing whole sentences? Or selected words? How much time you can invest in it? Any experience with signal processing and machine learning? You could start with one of state-of-the-art neural networks (or alike) that tackled similar problem and check its performance on your data set. It's a vast subject, you could do PhD on it.

Comment: @LukaszTracewski Thank you for responding. The truth is I am in my first sem as masters student in CS and I am starting to work early on my thesis. I still have 1 year to allot to this. I searched references on this matter however, only major languages are supported. Can you provide me references or link where I can start reading about Speech to Text in my own dialects? This would be a big help for me.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.

Answer (score 0):

To work on text-to-speech for unusual dialects is a big challenge since frequently the audio models do not exist and have to be created from scratch. A good place to start is with one of the tutorials from http://voxforge.org. At this site you will find not only the tutorials involving a number of audio decoders and model generators but also a useful forum where students of various languages other than English have found solutions related to their own dialect problems.

A general plan might be as follows: build a simple English model following the examples given to get used to the terminology and concepts and process involved. Given your inevitable success with English, you can then turn your possession of a native corpus to advantage by building models for your own dialect. It is a reasonable goal and has been done many times before. Be warned however that to get good recognition across a broad vocabulary you will need a very comprehensive corpus data set.

Comment: Thank you so much for the insights @Colin. I will start reading through the site's tutorial. Hope, this will be a good start for me.